# Quero alinhar o meu menu para o centro

Tags: html, css

```
#menu ul a:hover{
        background: #0186ba;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);    
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul li:last-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;

}
```

Este é o resultado atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero por esse menu alinhado ao centro mas até agora tudo o que tentei nada funcionou ...

CODIGO HTML

```
<html>
    <title></title>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <br>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="site.html">Pagina Inicial</a>
            </li>
            <li>    <a href="#">Produtos</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="inserir.html">Inserir</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="menuprodutos.html">Ver Produtos no Site</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="procurar.html">Procurar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="remover.html">Eliminar</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="listar.php">Listar</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>    <a href="site.html">A nossa Empresa</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="empresa.html">Hist&oacute;ria</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="val.html">Valores</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="cont.html">Contactos</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="email.html">Contacte-nos </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>    <a href="formulario.html">Formul&aacute;rio </a>
            </li>
            <li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <br>

        <body background="stardust.png">
            <div id="bodyy">
                <center>
                    <BR>
                    <BR>
                    <BR>
                    <BR>
                    <BR>

<h1> <font color="white">Inserir Novo Produto</font> </h1>

                    <form name="form1" method="post" action="inserir.php">
<font color="white">Codigo:</font>
                        <Input type="text" name="codproduto">
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        </input>
<font color="white">Nome:</font>
                        <input type="text" name="nomeproduto"></input>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
<font color="white">Quantidade:</font>
                        <input type="text" name="quantidade"></input>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Inserir" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Apagar dados" />
                </center>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                </form>
            </div>
            <script>
                function valida(form) {
                    if (form.codproduto.value == "") {
                        alert("Preencha o código corretamente.");
                        form.codigo.focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                    function valida(form) {
                        if (form.nomeproduto.value == "") {
                            alert("Preencha o nome corretamente.");
                            form.nome.focus();
                            return false;
                        }

                        function valida(form) {
                            if (form.quantidade.value == "") {
                                alert("Preencha a quantidade corretamente.");
                                form.codigo.focus();
                                return false;
                            }
            </script>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: você poderia ter editado a outra, não precisava criar uma nova, fica de aviso para suas próximas perguntas

Comment: João, boa! pode juntar html também?

Comment: @João, pode melhorar este jsFiddle para reproduzir o seu problema? Acho que falta pelo menos a informação de `estilo.css`: __http://jsfiddle.net/frLfS/__

Answer (score 3):

Tenta por mais informações da próxima vez, pra fica mais fácil de entender o problema, mas pelo que a imagem mostra acho que eu sei o que você quer.

Para alcança o efeito que você deseja, acredito que seja necessário fazer algumas modificações. A primeira seria por seu menu dentro de um `<div>` e essa div teria o seu estilo de borda arredonda, background e os outros efeitos, que hoje tem no menu. E o código css para o seu menu, adicionaria o seguinte código:

```
#menu{
 margin: auto; /* esse cara vai centralizar*/
 max-width: 800px; /* a largura máxima para o seu menu, para que ele possa ser centralizado. */
}
```

Outra forma seria você mudar o `display`, caso você não saiba o tamanho definido.

```
#menu{
 display: table;
 margin: auto;
}
```

*Lembre-se sempre de declarar um DOCTYPE para o seu html, para isso coloque na primeira linha o codigo*

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- DocType do HTML5, por exemplo -->
```

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta é antiga mas a dúvida ainda persiste, como este é um dos primeiros posts que aparecem no google, não custa atualizar, principalmente se você ainda não conhece flex-box!
coloque o menu dentro de uma div ou qualquer elemento que vai ser o pai.
insira este css:

```css
.div-pai{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

simples assim!
isso ainda elimina o float: left, ou display: inline-block; ou de determinar uma largura para a div pai!
segue link bastante informações sobre flex-box 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

#### Dá uma olhada se dessa forma serve pra você, costumo fazer assim:

#### http://codepen.io/anon/pen/npsHv

```
#menu{
  max-width: 960px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul{
  display: none;
}
#menu li:hover ul{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}
#menu li:hover ul li{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="site.html">Pagina Inicial</a></li>
    <li>    
      <a href="#">Produtos</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="inserir.html">Inserir</a></li>
        <li><a href="menuprodutos.html">Ver Produtos no Site</a></li>
        <li><a href="procurar.html">Procurar</a></li>
        <li><a href="remover.html">Eliminar</a></li>
        <li><a href="listar.php">Listar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>    
      <a href="site.html">A nossa Empresa</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="empresa.html">Hist&oacute;ria</a></li>
        <li><a href="val.html">Valores</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="cont.html">Contactos</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="email.html">Contacte-nos </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>    
      <a href="formulario.html">Formul&aacute;rio</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente isso pra mim resolve:

```
ul{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Dá uma olhada nisso:

http://jsfiddle.net/7hjPe/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; left: 50%; margin-left: auto; text-align: center;">
 <ul id="menu">
 <li>teste</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

width você põe o tamanho que quiser.

Answer (score -1):

Desenhe seu menu dentro de uma div , conforme abaixo e jogue o style do menu para margin:"auto"

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <ul id="menu" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  "seu menu"
  </ul>
</div>
```